# Is the app age rating a warning?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I would like to know if the app age rating is a warning. This is a very simple question but the answer is important for me. For example, by default, will people under 17 be able to download an app whose age rating is +17?
Is it just a warning? Is it only forbidden to download with parental control or something?

I would be glad to know if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.bewebsmart.com/ipod-ipad-iphone/how-to-restrict-apps-by-rating/

If Parental Control restricts a certain age criteria, yes it can be a filter. There are filters like 9+, 13+ etc. If all apps are allowed by the admin, no warning will be seen on the basis of age restriction. It will be just metric to judge content of the app.

Comment: so is it just warning?

Comment: @Auyem relevant for people who are affected. Just like "compatible with" info.

Comment: ok ty for your answer but is the phone gonna say "no way" if the user is minor and like really forbid it?

Comment: @Auyem Only if the admin restricts the apps with a certain age rating like 4,9,13,17

Comment: excuse me for all the questions but could please elaborate about the meaning of "admin" pls: is it the developer or the owner of the phone

Comment: @Auyem  no issues, By admin I refer to whoever sets the parental control on the iPhone. Developer has no say in that matter. For eg, in most schools, Computers are managed by an admin and there aren't much permissions given to the students to change things there. But on the other hand, I am in control of my iPhone and can use all the apps I want. But if the iPhone had parental controls by my parents, things  would be different..